# Wondering about Virtuoso's database commit durability – switch settings ?)

Tags: switch-statement, settings, virtuoso

I am running/testing the openlinksw.com Virtuoso database server and am noticing something odd – there appears to be no transaction logging.
Likely there is a switch/parm that needs to be set to enable logging of the individual commits/transactions, but I have not found in the documentation.
I have a script that looks like this:

```
set autocommit manual;
ttlp(file_to_string_output ('./events.nq/00000000'), 'bruce', 'bob', 512);
commit work;
ttlp(file_to_string_output ('./events.nq/00000001'), 'bruce', 'bob', 512);
commit work;
<repeat ttlp/commit pair many times>
```

Each of the 19,978 input files contains 50 quads.

I ran:

```
bin/isql < script.sql
```

and while it was running, I ran 'vmstat 1'.  The script takes about 4
minutes to finish, which gives a rate of about 83 commits per second.
However, vmstat's 'bo' (blocks out) column only occassionally showed
disk i/o.  Most of the time, 'bo' was zero, with occassional bursts of
activity.  I would expect that, for each commit to be durable, there
would have to be at least a small bit of i/o per commit for
transaction logging.  Am I doing something wrong?  I'm using the
default database parameters.

Example vmstat 1 output:

```
procs -----------memory----------      ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu-----
r  b   swpd   free   buff   cache      si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
2  0 113900 34730612 527836 11647812    0    0     0     0 4024 2928  6  1 94  0  0
1  0 113900 34729992 527840 11647876    0    0     0    36 4035 2727  6  0 93  1  0
2  0 113900 34729392 527840 11648440    0    0     0     0 3799 2612  6  1 94  0  0
1  0 113900 34728896 527840 11649004    0    0     0     0 3814 2693  6  0 94  0  0
1  0 113900 34724100 527840 11649556    0    0     0     0 3775 2653  6  1 94  0  0
1  0 113900 34723008 527840 11650128    0    0     0     8 3696 2838  6  0 94  0  0
1  0 113900 34722512 527844 11650708    0    0     0    16 3594 2996  6  0 93  0  0
1  0 113900 34721892 527844 11651868    0    0     0     0 4073 3066  6  0 94  0  0
1  0 113900 34721272 527844 11652488    0    0     0     0 4175 3077  6  1 94  0  0
1  0 113900 34721024 527844 11652568    0    0     0  5912 3744 2929  6  1 94  0  0
1  0 113900 34719540 527844 11653696    0    0     0    60 3786 3143  6  1 93  0  0
1  0 113900 34719044 527844 11653772    0    0     0    32 3809 2911  6  1 94  0  0
1  0 113900 34718052 527844 11654396    0    0     0     0 3963 2842  6  1 94  0  0
1  0 113900 34717060 527844 11654988    0    0     0     0 3956 2904  6  1 94  0  0
1  0 113900 34714748 527844 11656140    0    0     0     0 3920 2928  6  1 94  0  0
1  0 113900 34714144 527844 11656212    0    0     0     4 4059 2984  6  1 93  1  0
1  0 113900 34713656 527848 11657360    0    0     0    16 3945 2908  6  1 94  0  0
1  0 113900 34712540 527848 11657972    0    0     0     0 3978 2984  6  1 93  0  0
1  0 113900 34712044 527848 11658052    0    0     0     0 3758 2889  6  1 94  0  0
1  0 113900 34711088 527848 11658640    0    0     0     0 3643 2712  6  1 94  0  0
1  0 113900 34710468 527848 11659224    0    0     0     0 3763 2812  6  1 94  0  0
```

Running on 
Version: 7.1
64-bit linux